# PDF Details/Specific Page Previews in Rails 5.2 Active Storage

Tags: pdf, rails-activestorage, ruby-on-rails-5.2

I've been working on a tool that breaks down PDF files by pages so that I can display specific pages on a webpage. I spent a couple of days trying to research ways to do that using Active Storage purely, but couldn't find a way to do so. I ended up folding and using a gem [pdftoimage](https://github.com/robflynn/pdftoimage), however I've come to a point where pdftoimage is providing me with an error:

```
Syntax Error: Couldn't find trailer dictionary
Syntax Error: Couldn't find trailer dictionary
Syntax Error: Couldn't read xref table
```

I was curious to see if Active Storage has this same issue with this specific file and it doesn't when I run a preview, It simply displays the image. From what I can see Active Storage doesn't have any out of the box methods to access individual pages, or details about how many pages there are in the PDF file.

Does anyone know of any little known ideas on how to get access to individual pages? I'd prefer to not have to covert the PDF to images if I don't have to, as the quality always drops significantly.

Comment: So do you just need to access individual pages for some kind of information? Or do you need individual pages converted to images? The former is easily achieved by using a PDF library, the latter is a bit more involved.

Comment: I need to display each page as I put a user interactive layer over the pages. So I need to also know how many pages I need to do that for.

Comment: If it is just the number of pages you need, the pdftoimage gem has a `#page_count` method - https://github.com/robflynn/pdftoimage/blob/master/lib/pdftoimage.rb#L93.

As for the error you get: It might be from a corrupt but correctable PDF file (corrupt = not valid according to spec, correcctable = not that corrupted that it can't be recovered).